# javascript filter and slice does not work properly

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have the following code:

```
conditions.slice(0).filter(condition => condition.processsteptemplate === stepId);
```

It should slice some objects out of an array. Problem is that the === does not match so all elements are still in the array ...

whats  my fail

**UPDATE:**

**Sample Code:**

```js
var conditions = [{
      id: 14,
      conditiontype: 1,
      processsteptemplate: 9,
      deleted: false,
      processTemplate_id: 0
    },
    {
      id: 15,
      conditiontype: 1,
      processsteptemplate: 9,
      deleted: false,
      processTemplate_id: 0
    },
    {
      id: 16,
      conditiontype: 1,
      processsteptemplate: 10,
      deleted: false,
      processTemplate_id: 0
    }
  ],
  stepId = 9;
  
const output = conditions.slice(0).filter(condition => condition.processsteptemplate === stepId);
console.log(output)
```

Comment: Why `conditions.slice(0).filter`? `filter` will anyways return another array.

Comment: just remove slice?

Comment: try `var output = conditions.filter(x => x.processsTemplate === stepId); console.log(output)`. Point is, `filter` will never manipulate your original array. It will return a list of filtered values

Comment: already tried ... same result

Comment: slice has no effect here as filter won't alter the conditions array but instead **returns** a new one: `var metConditions = conditons.filter...`

Comment: added the input above

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: expected output is that the one with `processsteptemplate=10` is removed

Comment: @Felix I just wrapped your code in a snippet and logged the output. Please check and specify, what is incorrect/missing

Comment: missing was I haven't assigned the response to a new var

Comment: it works well for me what is the problem I dont get it? Also why you use slice?

Comment: `array#filter` doesn't alter the array, it just return a subset of items satisfying the condition.

Comment: at all guys thanks for downvote!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here the array with processsteptemplate = 10 is removed

```js
let arr = [
{id: 14, conditiontype: 1, processsteptemplate: 9, deleted: false, processTemplate_id: 0},
{id: 15, conditiontype: 1, processsteptemplate: 9, deleted: false, processTemplate_id: 0},
{id: 16, conditiontype: 1, processsteptemplate: 10, deleted: false, processTemplate_id: 0}
]

let step = 9;

let result = arr.filter((e) => e.processsteptemplate === step);

console.log(result);
```

What you were probably doing wrong was that you were assuming

```
arr.filter((e) => e.processsteptemplate === step);
```

would change the value in the current array, that is not true, it would return a new array which is now stored in **result** as you can now see in the above code snippet

Comment: To be honest, I addressed this in comments already. Also, questions like this can be resolved if you read the documentation. So answering them, is something, inn my POV, wrong. I'll still take my vote, as it does answer the question.